# Strings indexing tool for binary files

Tags: indexing, binaryfiles, binary-data, computer-forensics

Very often I've to deal with very large binary files (from 50 to 500Gb), in different formats, which contains basically mixed data including strings.

I need to index the strings inside the file, creating a database or an index, so I can do quick searches (basic search or complex with regex). The output of the search should be of course the offset of the found string in the binary file.

Does anyone know a tool, framework or library which can help me on this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can run 'strings -t d' (Linux / OS X) on it to pull out strings with their corresponding offset and then put that into Solr or Elastic.   If you want more than just ASCII though, it gets more complex.

[Autopsy](http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/) has its own strings extraction code (for UTF-8 and UTF-16) and puts it into Solr (and uses Tika if the file format is supported), but it doesn't record the offset from a binary file, so it may not meet your needs.